# Averaging subject-grouped dataframe after excluding zeroes

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R containing data from several subjects (DF). It looks like the following:

(DF):

```
ID       CSF1PO  CSF1PO.1  D10S1248  D10S1248.1  D12S391  D12S391.1
203078   0       -9        15          15        18       20
203078   -9      -9        14          15        17       19
203079   10      11        14          16        -9       -9
203079   0       12        14          17        -9       -9
203080   10      12        13          13        -9       -9
203080   10      11        14          16        -9       -9
203081   0       12        14          16        -9       -9
203081   11      12        15          16        -9       -9
203082   0       11        13          15        -9       -9
203082   0       11        13          14        -9       -9
```

I need to average values in `CSF1PO`, grouped according to `ID`, after having excluded the zeroes.

I have tried to first replace the zeroes with `NA` using:

```
DF$CSF1P0[DF$CSF1P0==0]<-NA
```

And then use `group_by` and mean in the following fashion:

```
library(dplyr)
grouped<-group_by(DF, id)
averages<-summarize(grouped, avg=mean(CSF1P0), NA.arm=TRUE)
```

However, the result I get is a single value containing the average of all subjects, with zeroes excluded, as opposed to the average of `ID`-grouped chunks with zeroes excluded. The `group_by` does not appear to be working properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `na.rm = TRUE` should be inside the `)` i.e. `mean(CSF1P0, na.rm = TRUE)`.  Also, you don't need to convert to NA, `DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(avg = mean(CSF1PO[CSF1PO!=0]))`

Comment: Also, you can use `filter` to remove those rows with `0` first (i.e., `filter(CSF1P0 !=0)`), then group and summarise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two slightly different ways to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% mutate(CSF1PO=replace(CSF1PO,CSF1PO==0,NA)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% summarise(avg=mean(CSF1PO,na.rm=TRUE))
```

(this gives `NaN` for ID=203082 because there are no non-`NA` values) or

```
dd %>% filter(CSF1PO!=0) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% summarise(avg=mean(CSF1PO))
```

(this excludes ID=203082)